# Identical tables in sql, find rows in one that aren't in the other

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables that are identical.  I want to find records that are in one but not in the other.

[image]

I have been working with this query but I am still getting duplicate records.

```
select a.storeid
    ,a.cashierid
    ,a.registerid
    ,a.timein
    ,a.timeout
    ,a.hours
    ,a.cashierprofile
from Timecard a
where not exists(select null from timecardssl b 
                        where b.StoreID = a.StoreID 
                             and b.CashierID = a.CashierID 
                             and b.RegisterID = a.RegisterID 
                             and b.TimeIn = a.TimeIn  
                             and b.TimeOut = a.TimeOut  
                             and b.hours = a.hours 
                             and b.CashierProfile = a.CashierProfile )
group by a.storeid
    ,a.cashierid
    ,a.registerid
    ,a.timein
    ,a.timeout
    ,a.hours
    ,a.cashierprofile 
having count(*) = 1
order by TimeIn desc
```

Comment: Why do you need the `Group By` at all? I thought that you just want to find all records that are in `a` but not in `b`.

Comment: for some reason there are multiple records in timecard that are the same.

Comment: Wondering what's wrong with the left outer join, but starting to wonder about the requirements as well...

Comment: Just a few records, inclusing what you expect as output would be much more helpful :) Still wondering what's with my left outer join?

Comment: I am just looking for a query that returns rows that are not in timecardssl when looking through timecard

Comment: That is exactly what most answers give you, so i think there is a discrepancy bnetween what you consider a different row and what SQL, and we, consider a different row.
Please try to give an example of a FULL record that is in our output that yuo do not want there, and why :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41480/discussion-between-user867621-and-oerkelens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like what LEFT OUTER JOIN was invented for :)
And if you have identical records in TimeCard and you do not want to see those, use DISTINCT

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.storeid,a.cashierid,a.registerid,a.timein,a.timeout,a.cashierprofile
      FROM Timecard a
LEFT OUTER JOIN timecardssl b 
        ON b.StoreID = a.StoreID 
       and b.CashierID = a.CashierID 
       and b.RegisterID = a.RegisterID     
       and b.TimeIn = a.TimeIn 
       and b.TimeOut = a.TimeOut 
       and b.CashierProfile = a.CashierProfile
     WHERE b.StoreID IS NULL;
```

Note that i left out the Hours column
Comparing the two Hours columns gave somehow strange results, which is something to look further in to.
But since Hours is the difference between timeIn and timeOut, leaving it out won't harm (if timeIn and timeOut are equal, you have an equal record already!)

Comment: when I run this the number of records returned is 352.  On record 200 there is a record with storeid = 10 cashiered = 4 registered = 1 timein = '2013-11-14 08:57:02.000' timeout = '2013-11-15 10:20:14.000' hours = '25.38333' and cashierprofile = OPEN

Comment: When I run a query against timecardssl where this isn't supposed to be because that is what this query is trying to do.  Find records that are in timecard that are not in timecardssl.  It returns results.

Comment: yes, so? I just went through the trouble of creating your table and inserting all the data.
And guess what? That record does NOT exist in your provided data!

Comment: Do you know why it would return that record when it isn't in the timecard database?

Comment: So if I use your query but take our the joining on the hours it seems to work just fine.  Thank you for your help... so much

Comment: So the only remaining question is why (real)25.38333 != (real)25.38333 according to SQL server... :)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.storeid, a.cashierid, a.registerid, 
  a.timein, a.timeout, a.hours, a.cashierprofile
FROM Timecard a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT Null
  FROM timecardssl b 
  WHERE b.StoreID = a.StoreID 
  AND b.CashierID = a.CashierID 
  AND b.RegisterID = a.RegisterID
  AND b.TimeIn = a.TimeIn 
  AND b.TimeOut = a.TimeOut
  AND b.hours = a.hours 
  AND b.CashierProfile = a.CashierProfile 
)
ORDER BY TimeIn desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Records in the `timecard` table that are not in the `timecardsssl` table.

```
SELECT storeid
     , cashierid
     , registerid
     , timein
     , timeout
     , hours
     , cashierprofile
FROM   timecard

EXCEPT

SELECT storeid
     , cashierid
     , registerid
     , timein
     , timeout
     , hours
     , cashierprofile
FROM   timecardssl
```

Records in the `timecardssl` table that are not in the `timecards` table.

```
SELECT storeid
     , cashierid
     , registerid
     , timein
     , timeout
     , hours
     , cashierprofile
FROM   timecardssl

EXCEPT

SELECT storeid
     , cashierid
     , registerid
     , timein
     , timeout
     , hours
     , cashierprofile
FROM   timecard
```

Comment: @user867621 Try adding `DISTINCT` to each `SELECT`

Comment: Then I fear your requirements aren't clear to me. Can you expand your question to include sample data and your desired output. Make sure you include these "duplicates" in your sample data.

Comment: my desired output is just to find rows that aren't in the timecardssl table.  When I run your query and I look at the records returned and try a select * from timecardssl where storeid = 10 and cashierid = 4 and registerid = 1 and timein = '2013-08-09 07:05:53.000'  I get records in timecardssl

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Timecard
UNION DISTINCT ...
FROM timecardssl 
GROUP BY ... 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: this returned 4100 rows instead of 350's

Comment: It may work if you do a SELECT DISTINCT instead of a simple SELECT.